# GroupBy causing trouble

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a DataGridView that I must fill with a query, and here is my query :

```
from Per in db.personne
join Dep in db.deplacement_personne 
on new { deplacement_personne = Per.num_personne } equals new { 
deplacement_personne = Dep.num_personne } into depPersAssign
from depPers in depPersAssign.DefaultIfEmpty()
where !(from Dep in db.deplacement_personne where Dep.id_deplacement == 
numDeplacement select Dep.num_personne).Contains(Per.num_personne)
select Per
```

I don't know how to put a 'groupBy'. What I tried :

```
from Per in db.personne
join Dep in db.deplacement_personne 
on new { deplacement_personne = Per.num_personne } equals new { 
deplacement_personne = Dep.num_personne } into depPersAssign
from depPers in depPersAssign.DefaultIfEmpty()
where !(from Dep in db.deplacement_personne where Dep.id_deplacement == 
numDeplacement select Dep.num_personne).Contains(Per.num_personne)
group Per by Per.num_personne into pers
select Per
```

I need a List of an object (my entity) like this : `List<myEntity>`

Without the groupby, everything is going right, is there a way to do this easily?

Thanks you

Comment: Why do you need a `GroupBy`? You want a single list of entities, not groups, so it's not clear what you expect the `GroupBy` to do for you.

Comment: I need a GroupBy because there are multi-entities of "num_personne" in some cases but I only want to show one in my DataGridView.

Comment: Why not just remove the join to `Dep` since you're not using it in the results?

Comment: You just solved my problem! By changing my query again and again I forgot that I were still on a left join query... Thank you very much!